# Quaqua Theme takes much memory

Tags: java, swing, desktop-application, quaqua

Comparative to Other themes of swing(Sysnthetica & Substance etc.) QuaQua theme takes more memory. some times, some parts of the JFrames remain when it moves over the screen too. This problem affects only to law memory pcs.   I want to know whether there is any way to reduce this memory issue and make the application fast.

Answer (score 1):

[Quaqua](http://www.randelshofer.ch/quaqua/) offers two editions. If the smaller one doesn't meet your requirements directly, it may suggest how to construct a custom version.